# Как не терять центи при рассчете средств

Tags: golang, математика, int, числа-с-плавающей-точкой, decimal

Я храню значение в базе как int64 и оперирую int64, а не float, перемножаю на 100 и округляю до ближайшего. Но насколько я понял, при расчете налогов когда идет перемножение/деление я теряю цент, а это мне не позволительно.

```go
type Amount int

func NewFromFloat(f float64) Amount {
    return Amount (math.Round(f*100))
}

func (a Amount) Float() float64 {
    return float64(a) / 100
}

func (a Amount) Abs() Amount{
    if a < 0 {
        return -a
    }
    return a
}

func (a Amount) String() string {
    return strconv.FormatFloat(a.Float(), 'f', 2, 64)
}

func (a Amount) Tax(percent float64) Amount {
    return a+ ((a*NewFromFloat(percent))/100)/100
}
```

Как вариант решения проблемы, я предполагаю использовать пакет https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shopspring/decimal для работы с десятичными числами, но опять же, возникает вопрос не попадутся ли такие случаи как выше, не будет ли теряться цент на расчетах налогов

Comment: int64 содержит до 9223372036854775807, столько денег в мире нет. вместо того, чтобы хранить валюа + центы, скажем, 100 рублей и 32 цента, ханрите сразу в центах в системе, скажем 132 цента. 
если нужна еще точность, то решите для себя сколько чисел после запятой, скажем, 7 цифр. получается 10 в 12 степени валюта и 10 в 7 цента. все просто. 
все деньги мира вместе стоят меньше 10 в 12 степени

Comment: @SeniorPomidor так проблема в том, что когда работаю с процентами, при умножении/делении целочисленного типа и округлении выпадает проблема "лишнего цента". Плюс, минус считается правильно. Умножение будет работать правильно только в том случае, если нам нужно увеличить цену в N количество раз, а не перемножать между собой. Деление не правильно потому что округлится в какую-то сторону

Comment: Видится, что у вас проблема немного иного характера, т.к. ну будет у вас такой float=100.5 и и это уже 101 цент для вас или же 100? Вы же в базе в int-ах храните, но допустим, теперь у вас в БД лежат decimal, так при взаимодействии и отправке данных куда-то, вам их в int видимо все равно придется преобразовать и встанет та же проблема. Т.е. тут нужно определиться, в какую сторону вам допустимо округление, если не позволено отправлять float, а если позволено, то не стоило хранить в int-ах.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, для оперирования денежными единицами, используйте пакет с типом decimal. В рамках пакета есть богатый функционал, для этого типа. Встроенные числовые типы go не в коем случае не стоит использовать, для решения этой проблемы.

Comment: Спасибо. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кейсы когда проявляется потеря точности в операциях рода умножение/деление над целочисленным типом

Comment: У вас будет разделённая логика? Для целочисленных чисел и чисел с плавающей точкой?

Comment: Нет. Я уже в принципе понял и сам написал тест кейс. Нужно взять любое число которое не делиться без остатка, поделить его на 2 (округлится в большую сторону), потом умножить на 2 (округлится в меньшую сторону) и получим случай с разницей в 1 цент

Comment: а что за операции такие, в которых вы деньги умножаете и делите?)

Comment: Просчет процентов